# Are css variables slowing website?

Tags: css

If i have css with variable like this

```
:root {
    --my-red-color:#ad082a;
}
p{
    color:var(--my-red-color);
}
h1{
    color:var(--my-red-color);
}
```

Is it slower than approach without variables?

And if so, should we use variables?

I don't need it for anything, I am just curious.

Comment: i think it will depend on your whole CSS ... this is a very tiny example to judge with. All depend on your needs and how are you doing it

Comment: I figure that's a highly subjective matter.

Comment: Uhm… benchmark it…?

Comment: To be honest, I think this is a legit question that deserves a good investigative answer. Other people might be interested as well in the performance of CSS-variables, and therefore they should be able to find this without running a benchmark themselves.

Comment: I've not found them slowing the render, except when using many "fallbacks" as var(--myvar, var(--anothervalue, var( --thirdone , 'red' ))) that can be perceived if used too frequently.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](https://lisilinhart.info/posts/css-variables-performance) shows a nice answer, mainly about calc() function. It is also possible to do some tests here.

> TL;DR
>
> - be aware of style recalculations, since CSS Variables are inheritable — changing a variable on a parent can affect many children
> - prefer using single classes for elements to make style calculations easier for the browser
> - calc() has good performance with variables, but still has problems with browser support with certain units like deg or ms
> - prefer using setProperty rather than inline styles to set CSS variables in Javascript

Comment: Can you provide a summary of the content on that webpage? Your answer currently is not a stand-alone answer and will not be a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) any more when that website would cease to exist.